# Why do tables and text look different after upgrading from 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, upgrade-sharepoint

I had several 2010 sites containing html formatted tables and text (formatted html using " edit source" button on ribbon) after upgrading to sharepoint 2013 the table and text styling looked different.  The table boarders and fills were different and the text colors and sizes were different.  Why did the upgrade undo our html input?    We will move from 2013 to 2016 eventually - are there steps we can take to keep formatting stable through future migrations?

Answer (score 1):

Generally different styles are used in 2013. This is expected behavior. However, when going from 2013 to 2016, you should not have any styling change as the same styles are used for both products.